# ManagementException: Not found

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2003

I have a program which runs on some wearable terminals in our warehouse. These terminals connect via remote desktop to our server which actually hosts and runs this program.

This program takes a scan of product, launches another program (if it isn't already running for the current user) which handles some processing, then does some additional processing once finished. One issue I'm running into is checking if the second program is already running. I've tried a lot of different code but this is what I settled on as it seemed to work perfectly fine.

```
Private Function CheckPrintLabelRunning() As Boolean
    Dim selectQuery As String = "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'vbPrintLabel.exe'"
    Dim searcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery)
    Dim processList As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()

    For Each obj As System.Management.ManagementObject In processList
        Dim argList As String() = New String() {String.Empty, String.Empty}
        Dim returnVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList))
        If returnVal = 0 Then
            If argList(0).ToString.ToUpper = Environment.UserName.ToUpper Then
                Return True
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

On Thursday, while the users were using the application on the terminals, the following error message popped up in my error logs. This application has seemingly been closing itself down, hitting the main form's FormClosing event (indicating that it isn't a full crash, but something that is handled inappropriately or an environment crash perhaps?). Here is the exception:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Not found 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, Object[] args)
   at vbFullCasePicking.frmFullCasePicking.CheckPrintLabelRunning()
   at vbFullCasePicking.frmFullCasePicking.StartPrintLabelListener()
   at vbFullCasePicking.frmFullCasePicking.PrintLabel(Boolean blnSMPLabels, String strCartonID)
```

I would like to point out that in this particular issue, the application did not close itself down, but I am still curious about this error as it's the first I've seen it of all the months this has been in use.

EDIT: More info...the server the application runs on is Windows Server 2003. This issue has not generated any event log entries of any kind as far as we can see.

EDIT 2: I completely forgot about this, but [I have a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839605/checking-windows-user-associated-with-process) regarding this issue. I was initially querying all the processes which seemed to cause errors when multiple users would try to query at the same time. This is likely the same issue, then, just with a much smaller window. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason you're getting this error only after a few months could be that a repository related to the WMI service finally got corrupted. Have you tried [repairing the WMI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm)? [Try this if you're using Windows 7](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csstwplatform/archive/2011/05/20/how-to-reset-windows-7-wmi.aspx)

Comment: I've updated my question as I forgot to mention, that this isn't generating any event log entries. Wouldn't that create something in the windows server 2003 event logs?

Comment: Yes it would indeed...

Comment: We are going to run a utility to check for corruption/missing files on Friday anyway just to make sure there is nothing going amiss on the server (have to wait until Friday as all of our gun users are running on it right now).

Comment: No such luck came up as a result of the various checks run on the server. I am working on a different approach, by moving and reworking the code in vbPrintLabel.exe to reside in a .dll file instead, then reference it from the program run on the terminals. Thus, I won't even need to check the process list on the server so this should be a non-issue once implemented (not sure why it wasn't a dll in the first place, but it was written well before my time at this company). Thanks for the input.